# Removing movieclip in timeline - really gone?

Tags: actionscript-3

I want a explosion to play when a object hits another object. I do this so that when hitTestObject is true, I run this function

```
function createExplosion():void {
var explosion:Explosion = new Explosion(enemy.x, enemy.y);
this.parent.addChild(explosion);
}
```

Explosion class only consists of setting the input to it's x and y values. Then in explosion movieclip I have a few frames of a animation. It ends in a keyframe (i.e., as an action in that frame) with the following code:

```
stop();
this.parent.removeChild(this);
```

My question is. Is it really gone now? I had to add stop() to not get error 1009. That makes me suspect some event timer is still running around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing a display object from the display list, doesn't stop the animation or remove it from memory. It just removes it from the display list. Yes, you need to stop the animation and remove any event listeners that might be active for that object.

A display object is never truly gone until it is garbage collected. But that will not happen until no references to that object remain. So if you have a variable called explosion that references your display object, you need to set it to null after removing it from the display list :

```
explosion.stop();   // stop the animation
removeChild(explosion);  // remove from display list
explosion = null; // remove variable reference
// explosion now qualifies for garbage collection.
```

Keep in mind that this doesn't immediately remove the object from memory, it just makes it fair game for the garbage collector. You can google "AS3 Garbage Collection" to get more information on that process.

Comment: Ok. The object does not have any event listeners as a class. (I use a main event listener to move everything each frame.) But is there a event listener simply because there are several frames in the mc? (I.e., an implicit event listener somewhere that I have not created.) If so, how do I remove it?

Comment: As I noted in the answer, you stop the animation. The MovieClip class has the play/stop methods to handle that aspect.